# Android NDK Clang produces 23% slower binaries than GCC

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-ndk

I am working on application what emulates old operating system from 90'. I build c++ binaries with android ndk r10e with gcc 4.8. But, because google drops support for gcc, I want switch to clang. After updating ndk to r15 and successful build, I ran benchmarks(in r15 is default compiler clang, instead gcc like it was in ndk r10e). Result is that emulated system runs 23% slower. I did none changes to Android.mk and I use -O3 for optimizations. I only updated ndk. In ndk r15 is still possible switch to gcc 4.9. I did it and I got back lost performance. And even more, seems gcc 4.9 makes slightly better optimizations then gcc 4.8. But that's not important. Important is that google drops gcc for future ndk versions and I should switch to clang. I will be very happy if someone experienced with compilers can try bring some light to this mystery...From what I read on web I expected that clang will produce faster binaries or the same. And I didn't find special magic clang compiler flags what I must enable for Android.mk.

Many thanks

Comment: File a bug? This is the first we've heard of any performance regressions.

Comment: For a fun I tested similar application from other developer. In last build he switched to clang and result is the same, his applications runs around 22% slower too. Please what do you mean with file bug?

Comment: ah yes, report a bug

Comment: Did you file a bug report? We haven't been anything yet. Can't fix it if we don't know what's wrong...

Comment: It is reported on github in android ndk issues